# JVM crash dump : klass: 'java/util/TreeMap'

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

Here is the crash dump of my JVM.

```
Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000000072c9 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000002746b6050 is an oop
java.util.TreeMap 
 - klass: 'java/util/TreeMap'
RDX=0x000000021b96fc48 is an oop
java.util.TreeMap$KeySet 
 - klass: 'java/util/TreeMap$KeySet'
RSP=0x00000000321df850 is an unknown value
RBP=0x00000000321df8f9 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000321dfa00 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000001ceedc0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000321df880 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000009437a70b8 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 238
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000001ceedc8 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000021b96fc48 is an oop
java.util.TreeMap$KeySet 
 - klass: 'java/util/TreeMap$KeySet'
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000],  sp=0x00000000321df850,  free space=821118k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x31e6ec]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000003c083800 JavaThread "Thread-335557" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=66888, stack(0x000000006e4a0000,0x000000006e5a0000)]
```

[`Here is full dump`](http://pastebin.com/dYMncyk4)

Is there anything wrong with `TreeMap` and its `keySet` methods? Not well with reading dump. Any help ?

Comment: One thing really surprisng is the thread number which is `335557`, a rather big number.  Otherwise I would check you have a recent update of the JVM.  There is no way a bug in TreeSet or any other class can cause this error, it would have to be a bug in the JVM.

Comment: `7.0_21-b11` before asking for free help, how about at least trying to see if it has been fixed in the latest java version?

Comment: @the8472 Thanks for your help. I don't escape from errors. I'll try to learn from errors.